# Ansible not using hosts_vars

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to learn ansible via an online course and I'm having some trouble with assigning variables using host_vars.

I tried looking at previous posts but none of them quite mirror my situation and with this task being the first thing the course asks me to do, I don't actually know enough about ansible to figure out how to apply what's happening.

Basically I'm trying to run the following command:

```
ansible databases --limit db01 -m ping
```

The command is failing with an error saying that  the sudo password is missing. This makes sense to me as the class specifically instructed me to set become_ask_pass=False in the config file.

However, within the db01 file in my host_vars directory I have set become_ask_pass: True, which the class implies should be overwriting what is set in the .cfg file.

For whatever reason ansible seems to be ignoring the file. I will include the relevant files and directory structure below:

tree

```
 - ansible
    -ansible.cfg
    -ansible.cfg.bak
    -inventory
       -hosts.yml
       -host_vars
          -db01.yml
```

/home/name/ansible/ansible.cfg

```
[defaults]
inventory = /home/name/ansible/inventory/hosts.yml

[privilege_escalation]
become=True
become_method=sudo
become_user=root
```

/home/name/ansible/inventory/hosts.yml

```
all:
    hosts:
    children:
        webservers:
            hosts:
                web01:
                web02:
        databases:
            hosts:
                db01:
                db02:
```

/home/name/ansible/inventory/host_vars/ db01.yml

```
#Set variables for db01
---
become_ask_pass: True
```

Lastly here is the actual error output:

**db01| FAILED! => { "msg": "Missing sudo password"}**
[image: db01| FAILED! => { "msg": "Missing sudo password"}]

I would appreciate any input as to why this might be happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`become_ask_pass` is not the name of an ansible variable; it is a configuration item that can be placed in `ansible.cfg` (docs [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/intro_configuration.html#become-ask-pass)). Whether or not to ask for the `become` password is not something that can be set per-host; it can only be set globally either by adding `become_ask_pass=true` to `ansible.cfg` or by specifying `--ask-become-pass` (`-K`) on the command line.

Ansible will only ask for the become password once, and will use that password for all hosts.

Otherwise, your setup is correct: variables placed in `inventory/host_vars/db01.yml` will be available when running tasks on `db01`. You could verify that right now by comparing the output of:

```
ansible databases --limit databases -m debug -a 'var=become_ask_pass'
```

Which will output something like:

```
db01 | SUCCESS => {
    "become_ask_pass": true
}
db02 | SUCCESS => {
    "become_ask_pass": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

That verifies that Ansible is correctly reading the value from your `host_vars` file; it's just that the variable you're setting doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: Yup this seems to be the case. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation of the *sudo* become plugin

```
shell> ansible-doc -t become sudo
```

You can't set [*become_ask_pass*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-become-ask-pass) in a variable. Setting such a variable has no effect on the plugin. Instead, you can set *ansible_become_pass*. This way you can set different passwords for various users *become_user* and remote hosts.
For example,

```
shell> cat host_vars/db01/ansible_become_pass.yml
ansible_become_pass: "ansible become pass of *become_user* on db01"
```

```
shell> ansible databases --limit db01 -m debug -a 'var=ansible_become_pass'
db01 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_become_pass": "ansible become pass of *become_user* on db01"
}
```

[Encrypt](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html#encrypting-content-with-ansible-vault) the password.

Because *become_ask_pass* is a configuration key in the *
[privilege_escalation]* section of the configuration file you can't display the configuration by *debug: var=become_ask_pass*. In the code, use the lookup plugin *config* if you want to find out the current configuration. See

```
shell> ansible-doc -t lookup config
```

For example, the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: become_ask_pass
    - debug:
        msg: "DEFAULT_BECOME_ASK_PASS: {{ lookup('config', 'DEFAULT_BECOME_ASK_PASS') }}"
```

shows that setting the variable *become_ask_pass* has no effect on the configuration

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/db01/become_ask_pass.yml 
become_ask_pass: True
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook --limit db01 pb.yml 

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [db01] => 
  become_ask_pass: true

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [db01] => 
  msg: 'DEFAULT_BECOME_ASK_PASS: False'

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
db01: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```